# Probability that top 2 players (among $2^n$ players) meet in the final round of a chess tournament.

Tags: probability

We have $2^n$ players. Their skill levels are $\{1, 2, \ldots, 2^n\}$. They're placed in a chess tournament. The winner of each game is guaranteed to be the higher skill level person. What is the probability that players $2^n$ and $2^n - 1$ meet in the final round?

I solved this problem in 2 ways, and I am getting different answers.

---

First method:

Essentially, I looked at the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, 2^n\}$, and asked the question "how many ways can we permute this set such that if you cut the set in half, players $2^n$ and $2^n - 1$ end up in different halves. My intuition tells me this is simply 0.5... this is clearly and obviously not true for $n=1$ (2 players, probability 1 of meeting in final round) and $n=2$ (4 players, probability of 2/3 of meeting in final round), but I don't know why this intuition fails.

---

Second approach (this is apparently the correct answer):

In order for player $2^{n} - 1$ to reach the final round, it must be part of its own subgroup (essentially same idea as above). Consider 2 subgroups of equal size. The subgroup with player $2^n$ will always have player $2^n$ as the one coming out. If the other subgroup has player $2^n-1$, then it will always come out. So the question becomes what is the probability that player $2^n-1$ ends up in the second subgroup, i.e., the one without player $2^n$? Well the probability that it ends up in that second subgroup is clearly $\frac{2^{n}/2}{2^{n} - 1}$.

You see that this expression approaches 0.5 as $n$ gets larger.

My question is why does my first method and my intuition fail?

Comment: Because they are not independent: placing one player into a group reduces probability that the second player goes into the same group. Therefore, there is no symmetry. Also I don't understand how you got $2 (\frac 1 {2^{n-1}})^2$.

Comment: To see why 1st method fails, take $n=2$. There are three ways to split the four players into two groups of two, and two of those ways have players $3$ and $4$ in different brackets. In bridge, this is known as "the principle of restricted choice". It's why, if there are two key cards outstanding, then they are more likely to be in different hands than in the same hand.

Comment: @Dmitry Ah yes, I just realized that. It seems my first method assumes replacement and doesn't remove the space that one player occupies from the sample space. This is also the reason why as n gets large, the correct solution approaches 0.5, because forgetting about replacement matters less as $n$ gets large. Regarding your last part: I removed that paragraph. I wasn't sure where I was going with that.